# How to parse breadcrumbs in Ruby

Tags: html, ruby, xpath, nokogiri

How do I add pipe delimiter to my string from the HTML code I'm parsing?

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="results">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <nav class="breadcrumb-nav">
          <ol class="breadcrumb">
            <li>
              <a href="/">Home Page</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="link">Category Name</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="link">Sub Category Name</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="link">Another Sub Category Name</a>
            </li>
            <li class="highlight">
              <a href="link">Current Sub Category Page Name</a>
            </li>
          </ol>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My code:

```
puts page.xpath(".//*[@class='breadcrumb']//a").text
```

Displays:

> Home PageCategory NameSub Category NameAnother Sub Category NameCurrent Sub Category Page Name

I would like to have it displayed as

> Home Page | Category Name | Sub Category Name...

Answer (score 2):

You have to take the text of individual elements, then join with your delimiter:

```
page.xpath(".//*[@class='breadcrumb']//a").map(&:text).join(' | ')
```

Answer (score 0):

Better still; use CSS to style a delimiter. Using glyphs as delimiter is bad accessibility.

Comment: Ruby is still very new to me and have not coded in years. Would you provide an example David?

Comment: When you use a 'keyboard character' as a way to separate items, screenreaders will read them to the user. So, better to do something like .crumbitem {border-left: 1px solid green;} Or as fancy as you like. :)

Comment: Or check out Font Awesome. :)

Comment: Sounds cool! Data is going into a CSV file as a reference. Will keep this in mind for future though. Thanks!